# Regular expression match the word which may have special character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match the whole word in string using the Regular Expression in C#.net 
May be my pattern have the special character or not.

My Pattern: `\b(blessed')\b`

My Input:

```
Blessed' be Thou for all the joy
Blessed be Thou for all the joy
```

It does not match anything.

If I edit my pattern to: `\b(blessed)\b`

Than it match the 2 word which my string have but I want to match the word which have the `' (Single Quote)`

Online Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oI3nB5/1#pcre and http://regexr.com/3cq7q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\b` is a boundary between word characters and non-word characters. Both `"'"` (apostrophe) and `" "` (space) are non-word characters, so `\b` does not match between them. Use negative lookaround:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z'])([a-zA-Z']+)(?![a-zA-Z'])
```

"doesn't have a letter or an apostrophe before, then any number of letters or apostrophes, then doesn't have a letter or apostrophe after"... or if you want the literal `Blessed'`,

```
(?<![a-zA-Z'])(Blessed')(?![a-zA-Z'])
```

Comment: How can I pass the Word which have the Single Quote (') to Search in the input. For example I have to found the word (Blessed') in input string so how can I pass that Blessed' pattern for match, Because I want only that string which have the Blessed' word in it.

Comment: The word is not the problem, `\b` is. See my second example.

Comment: The issue is well known. Word boundary meaning depends on the context. Use unambiguous boundaries with (?<!\w) and (?!\w).